# How do I pass a TextInput value up from a React Navigation component to my main app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm stuck tying figure out how to pass a TextInput value up from a React Navigation component to my main app.  The following Expo Snack shows my code:  https://snack.expo.io/@nativedetroiter/test-passing-state-to-screens-and-back

**Desired behavior:**  When I run it, I want ***this.state.stateVar*** to take the value I enter into the TextInput box.

**Observed behavior:**  Although the console log shows handleChangeText() gets fired every time I press a key in the TextInput box, but it also shows that ***this.state.stateVar*** is "undefined".

Comment: can you check whether this is what you needed? https://snack.expo.io/HJksGPgNm

Comment: Thank you very much @AravindS, this is what I needed.  I think I understand.  It seems as though I need to create an intermediate state in the screen component.  When I handle that one, I can also call the handler in my main app that I passed to the component as a prop function.  Please log your response as an answer so I can check it as correct.

Comment: Sure! I will add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you missed is you have to get the input value during onchage and then send it to the any component. I created a state to locally save the what the user typed and  updated code is [here](http://snack.expo.io/HJksGPgNm) snack.expo.io/HJksGPgNm